# Display Totals in Quick Edit Mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, quick-edit, count

In SP Online, is there any way to display column count in Quick Edit mode in List views?

Datasheet view had this option to "Show Totals" but this seems to be missing with Quick Edit Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OOB method to display the column count in quick edit mode in list view in SharePoint online.

When we are in the quick edit mode, it will not count the items according to the column. Because the count of the items is dynamical.

After we exit the quick edit mode, it will count the items and display the count of the items.

Why do you want to display the column count in quick edit mode? Could you give me some details about the issue?

Comment: There is no issue, actually i just found that in "Quick Edit" mode totals was missing so thought of get it clarified. Also we mostly work in "Quick Edit" mode because of the total number of columns we had to update.Missing Totals in quick edit mode is very disappointing

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could mark the reply as the answer.